# Angular 2 low fps rates when scrolling

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem that a have multiple components displaying a row of table. The problem is when i scrooling a page a have a huge fps drop. Every component subscribe an data array from service. I dont use ''ngDoCheck'' but i still have a fps drop :/ . I use chrome timeline and i have a lot of event(mousmove).

May it be that i have to much components?  I remove every ngDoCheck and i observe when i moving mouse above table the processor in task manager is about 50% use. when i stop moving mouse it backs to normal

Comment: This might help https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14056#issuecomment-274641655. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8866, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1773#issuecomment-275825509

Comment: It doesnt help i add this and i still have in timeline a lot of Event(mousemvoe) and under this on timeline ZoneTask.invoke

Answer (score 0):

Registering the event handler outside Angulars zone should help until related issues are fixed:

```
constructor(zone:NgZone, elRef:ElementRef) {
  zone.runOutsideAngular(() => elRef.nativeElement.addEventHandler('scroll', 
  (e) => {
    if(some criteria) {
      zone.run(() => {
        // update model here
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Also performance meansurements only make sense in production mode.

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14056#issuecomment-274641655
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8866